# How to notate the set of functions into a Cartesian product space?

Tags: functions

I read that the set of function from a set $X$ to the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ can be notated by $\mathbb{R}^X$.

Now I am wondering what the corresponding notation is for the set of functions from $X$ to a Cartesian product space, e.g. $\mathbb{R}^n$.

$\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)^X$ looks cumbersome. But $\mathbb{R}^{n \cdot X}$ looks a bit strange too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you wrote, $(\mathbb{R}^n)^X$, is literally the set you ask for.

It is naturally isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n \times X}$; the exponent is the cartesian product of $X$ with a set of $n$ elements. I.e. $n$ denotes the set of indices you use to label the coordinates; note that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is also a function space!

There is a bijection $n \cdot X \cong n \times X$, where $n \cdot X$ denotes the disjoint union of $n$ copies of $X$, so that notation is fine too, although (IMO) rather uncommon.

Comment: But the disjoint union of $n$ copies of $X$ is the same (basically) as $n\times X$.

Comment: @Tobias: You're right. I spent the past 4 minutes grumbling over why that claim was bothering me; I needed someone else to say it was wrong too before it sunk in.

Comment: So basically, I should use $\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)^X$ rather than $\mathbb{R}^{n \times X}$. Because the latter is isomorphic but not the same, right?

Comment: @Daniel: Yes; if you need to  express that *exact* set, you need to use $(\mathbb{R}^n)^X$. For many purposes, however, the distinction between them doesn't really matter much.

Comment: @Hurkyl: I need to refer to the set of functions. So I guess it matters for that purpose, right?